# Pattern and picking out needed values from unknown forms using Regex with Java

Tags: java, regex

I am terrible at trying to figure out this Regex! It's, like everyone else, doesn't make much since.

The string looks like this:## Heading ##

> `15:26:04,017 INFO [stdout] (Log4j2-xxxxxxxxx-1) 2019-04-23 15:26:03,945 [ http-xxxxxxxxx-4] [ STANDARD] [ ] [ xxxxxxxxx:8] (rnal.loaders.xxxxxxxxx) INFO xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx|1xxxxxxxxx4|Rest|SystemManagement|v2|importxxxxxxxxxd1070581a|xxxxxxxxxPSUYP7A - The import WORK- PxxxxxxxxxWARNING #xxxxxxxxx.591 GMT`

The pattern looks like this when breaking the above up:

```
15:26:04
017
INFO 
stdout
Log4j2-xxxxxxxxx-1
2019-04-23 
15:26:03
http-xxxxxxxxx-4
STANDARD
[] 
[xxxxxxxxx:8] 
rnal.loaders.xxxxxxxxx
INFO
xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx
1xxxxxxxxx4
Rest
SystemManagement
v2
importxxxxxxxxxd1070581a
xxxxxxxxxPSUYP7A 
The import WORK- PxxxxxxxxxWARNING #xxxxxxxxx.591
GMT
```

Any help with this crazy pattern would be great! I've been told that using `[.*?]` would help with the `X` in brackets but it's still over my head and I don't know how to go about this the LONG LONG way around (.replace, .contains, .indexOf) but I know using Regex is much cleaner.

**UPDATE**
Yeah even with your suggestion(s) I am unable to come up with even a character being recognized.

I also noticed that the SSH log(s) are not all the same format:

```
12:30:58,818 INFO  [x] (x:x, x: [x], Partitions=[0,1,3]) lefd version : 0.11.0.3
```

So that above is different form:

```
15:26:04,017 INFO [stdout] (Log4j2-xxxxxxxxx-1) 2019-04-23 15:26:03,945 [ http-xxxxxxxxx-4] [ STANDARD] [ ] [ xxxxxxxxx:8] (rnal.loaders.xxxxxxxxx) INFO xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx|1xxxxxxxxx4|Rest|SystemManagement|v2|importxxxxxxxxxd1070581a|xxxxxxxxxPSUYP7A - The import WORK- PxxxxxxxxxWARNING #xxxxxxxxx.591 GMT
```

So in my opinion this is totally out of my realm of Regex knowledge - even if regex can split all of these up regardless of form.

Comment: your last 5 `X` does not match with text. Can you please clarify it? or it would be helpful if you can put value for each named capture group in front of it. e.g. `time:2019-04-23 15:26:03,945`

Comment: Regex writing "pro-tip" : start by matching a little part at the beginning of the string, check that it works, append new parts step by step and check at each step that it still works. Other than that you'll need to escape the `[` and `.` you want to match since those are meta-characters, and the `[.*?]` you mention should probably be `(.*?)` or even simply `.*?` (but that relies on the next tokens as a delimiter, which isn't always ideal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/9amXff/1) might help you to design a full regex and match your pattern. The pattern does not seem to be complicated, is just long:

```
([0-9:]+)(,[0-9]{3})\s([A-Z]+)\s[[a-z]+]\s(\(Log4j2-x{9}-1\))
```

One easy way for matching such long patterns is to use groups `()` and break the input strings into pieces.

---

It's not clear from your question, which chars are dynamic or static, and what might be `x`. However, you might simply use groups and continue this RegEx and create a full match:

[image]

Comment: I have updated my OP to reflect another issue I seen - the log output doesn't seem to be the same format all across the board.

Comment: Hey @Emma the "x"'s are there to censor data that is sensitive and I did not want to show.